# Visual Studio and MSBuild fire BeforeBuild differently on a WiX project

Tags: msbuild, wix

I have a [WiX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WiX) (Windows installer XML) v3, project which contains references to other projects in my solution. I am using the copy task inside the BeforeBuild event of the WiX project to collect some of the output of the references projects for later use my [Heat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WiX#Tallow.2FHeat).

When I build the WiX project (not the solution) inside Visual Studio, each of the referenced projects is build before my WiX project and once they are built, the BeforeBuild event on my WiX project fires and then the WiX project itself is built. This is the behaviour I expect - I am able to access files from the bin directories of the references projects in the WiX BeforeBuild and use them as I please before the WiX project executes [Candle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WiX#Candle).

The problem I am having is when I build the WiX file via [MSBuild](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MSBuild) I am finding that the BeforeBuild event fires straight away BEFORE any of the referenced projects. This difference in behaviour means that I cannot make use of the outputs of the referenced projects when building from the command line.

Why is BeforeBuild executing at a different point in time when run via MSBuild on the command line to inside Visual Studio?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you are building inside Visual Studio, the solution dependencies (which can be explicit or based on the project references) are used to determine which projects need to be built and a separate build is kicked off for each of them. This is necessary since solutions can also contain projects that are not built using MSBuild and other projects have explicit dependencies set in the solution for them. The side effect is that each project is treated as a stand-alone build, thus ensuring the right `BeforeBuild` order for you..

If you are building from the command line using MSBuild, the dependency projects are resolved (and built if necessary) during the `ResolveReferences` target. The `BeforeBuild` target and `PreBuild` event (executed from the `PreBuildEvent` target) are both performed before the `ResolveReferences` target. Thus the dependent project `BeforeBuild` target ends up executing before the build for the dependency project is kicked off.

Note that from a point of view of a single project, `BeforeBuild` target does make sense to be executed before resolving dependencies, as the dependency resolution might itself depend on the `BeforeBuild` target output. For example, `BeforeBuild` might execute a custom script to get the latest copy of any dependency projects from the [SCM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_configuration_management).

Comment: Thanks Franci.Sounds like BeforeBuild is not what I need. Is there an event I can override in my WIX project that will fire after the ResolveReferences target has built all the referenced projects?

Comment: @DavEvans, look at the AfterResolveReferences target, either via the BeforeTargets or AfterTargets attribute.  Alternately, the Compile target with the BeforeTargets attribute:  
  
`<Target Name="MyCustomTarget" AfterTargets="AfterResolveReferences"><Message Text="Do stuff AfterTargets:AfterResolveReferences here." Importance="High" /></Target>  
<Target Name="MyOtherCustomTarget" BeforeTargets="Compile"><Message Text="Do stuff BeforeTargets:Compile here." Importance="High" /></Target>`